# dynamic ng-repeat field using $index

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I had set of fields like the following image
[Field_Group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swRbU.png)

Whenever click the add button then I will add another row with the same set of data like as follows
[Updated_Fields_Group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tcE7.png)

Below is my code:

```
    <div>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" name="addnewrow" ng-click="addNew()">Add</button>
    </div>
    <div id="details_$index" ng-repeat="row in rows track by $index">
       <div class="form-group ">
          <label class="col-md-2 control-label">{{Row $index}}
          </label>
          <div class="col-md-4" >
             <input id="email_{{$index}}" type="text" class="form-control"  name="email_{{$index}}" placeholder="email" ng-model="row_$index.email" ng-keyup="getListOfEmails(row_$index.email,$index)"  />
             <ul class="list-group emailDropDownUL">
                <li class="list-group-item emailDropDownLI" ng-repeat="email in list_of_emails_$index" ng-click="updateEmailDetails(row_$index.email,$index)" >{{email_$index}}</li>
             </ul>

          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
             <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" name="mobile_{{$index}}" id="mobile_{{$index}}" ng-model="row_$index.mobile" placeholder="Mobile" class="form-control" numbers-only/>

             </div>
          </div>
       </div>

    </div>
    </code>
```

When add button invoked, following json will push into the ***rows***

> {'firstname':"",'lastname':"",'email':"",'mobile':""}

**Here is the problem**

When a user types the text in "email" field, it's looking into DB and send a list of related emails to the front end.

Now issue was, the "rows" are dynamic, i'm using ng-repeat like below

> ng-repeat="email in list_of_emails_$index"

But here `list_of_emails_$index` not working.

if I removed `_$index`, then it'll populate in all email fields

[without _$index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oULOX.png)

***Finally, how can we create dynamic ng-repeat ***

Comment: Can you also provide the code from your js and HTMl

Comment: I think it is problem with `ng-model`, `ng-model` should be different. Please add some code

Comment: Thanks @Vivek. The actual problem with ng-repeat. I need to create a dynamic ng-repeat variable. For more details, updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this out it will help you.

```
<div id="details_$index" ng-repeat="row in rows track by $index">
    <div class="form-group ">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input id="email_{{$index}}" type="text" class="form-control" name="email_{{$index}}" placeholder="email" ng-model="row_$index.email" ng-keyup="getListOfEmails(row_$index.email,$index)" />
            <ul class="list-group emailDropDownUL">
                <!--This is how you can find and use dynamic variables from scope. I too have struggled a lot from similar kind of issue.-->
                <li class="list-group-item emailDropDownLI" ng-repeat="email in this['list_of_emails_'+ $index]" >{{email}}</li>
            </ul>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" name="mobile_{{$index}}" id="mobile_{{$index}}" ng-model="row_$index.mobile" placeholder="Mobile" class="form-control" numbers-only />

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
    app.controller("myCtrl", function ($scope) {

        //Setting up data
        $scope.rows = [];
        $scope.row = {};
        $scope.row.Name = "Test1";
        $scope.rows.push($scope.row);
        $scope.row = {};
        $scope.row.Name = "Test2";
        $scope.rows.push($scope.row);
        $scope.row = {};
        $scope.row.Name = "Test3";
        $scope.rows.push($scope.row);
        $scope.row = {};
        $scope.row.Name = "Test4";
        $scope.rows.push($scope.row);


        //fetching data on some event
        $scope.getListOfEmails = function (email,index) {
            $scope['list_of_emails_' + index] = ['email1', 'email2', 'email3']
        }
```

});

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <div id="details_$index" ng-repeat="row in rows track by $index">
        <div class="form-group ">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input id="email_{{$index}}" type="text" class="form-control" name="email_{{$index}}" placeholder="email" ng-model="row_$index.email" ng-keyup="getListOfEmails(row_$index.email,$index)" />
                <ul class="list-group emailDropDownUL">
                    <!--This is how you can find and use dynamic variables from scope. I too have struggled a lot from similar kind of issue.-->
                    <li class="list-group-item emailDropDownLI" ng-repeat="email in this['list_of_emails_'+ $index]" >{{email}}</li>
                </ul>

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" name="mobile_{{$index}}" id="mobile_{{$index}}" ng-model="row_$index.mobile" placeholder="Mobile" class="form-control" numbers-only />

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
        app.controller("myCtrl", function ($scope) {

            //Setting up data
            $scope.rows = [];
            $scope.row = {};
            $scope.row.Name = "Test1";
            $scope.rows.push($scope.row);
            $scope.row = {};
            $scope.row.Name = "Test2";
            $scope.rows.push($scope.row);
            $scope.row = {};
            $scope.row.Name = "Test3";
            $scope.rows.push($scope.row);
            $scope.row = {};
            $scope.row.Name = "Test4";
            $scope.rows.push($scope.row);


            //fetching data on some event
            $scope.getListOfEmails = function (email,index) {
                $scope['list_of_emails_' + index] = ['email1', 'email2', 'email3']
            }

     });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @Vivek. I will try it out and update the status

Comment: Thanks @vivek. It is working. But, I had another issue.

Comment: For select the email from the list of emails I used to call an updateEmailDetails() function. In this function, I'm fetching the data related to that email id from backend and set the values for mobile,firstname,lastname fields.
So, While setting the data using javascript using 
    $scope['interviewer_'+index].mobile = data.mobile;
But, it is throws an error of  "Cannot set property 'email' of undefined"
Please check once

Comment: The above issue is resolved by adding

 var obj = {'firstname':data.firstname,'lastname':data.lastname,'email':data.email,'mobile':data.mobile};
$scope.interviewers_emails[index]= obj;

Comment: Good to know :)

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**

*Here is the problem when I entered a value in one email field in a row then it will be populated in remaining email field of all rows*

**This happens if you have same `ng-model`**

**Solution:**

As far as I understand think it is problem with `ng-model`, 
**ng-model should be different for all fields.**

Here is an example

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<div ng-repeat="email in emails">
<input type="email" ng-model="email.email" >
<input type="text" name="mobile_{{$index}}" id="mobile_{{$index}}" ng-model="email.mobile" placeholder="Mobile" class="form-control"/>

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.emails = [
  {id: 1, email: "email1", mobile: "9848022338"},
  {id: 2, email: "email2", mobile: "1234567890"}
    ]
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Please run the above code**

[**Here is a working DEMO**](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FRTAIT8AIPR2)

**Ps:** To make it dynamic as you have taken array of objects are required and in `ngModel` you can take `email.email` and `email.mobile` etc

Comment: thanks, @Sravan . The actual issue is "how can we create dynamic ng-repeat field". I updated question. Please check once

Comment: @SarvaniTetali, I made it dynamic please check now

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**
*Dynamic ng-repeat*

I create a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Y68GjAYCOYE5Gnor2oG1?p=preview)

i suppose you have emails in array similar following js variables:

```
$scope.list_of_emails_0 = ['email1', 'email2', 'email3'];
$scope.list_of_emails_1 = ['email4', 'email5', 'email6'];
// ...
```

Can you create an object instead separated variables?

```
$scope.list_of_emails = {
   "0" : ['email1', 'email2', 'email3'],
   "1" : ['email4', 'email5', 'email6']
};
```

If you can do that, you can also loop with ng-repeat throw that object

```
<div ng-repeat="row in rows">
  <h1>{{row}} - index: {{$index}}</h1>
  <p ng-repeat="email in list_of_emails[$index]">{{email}}</p>
</div>
```

I hope it's helpful!

Comment: Thanks @ Luca. I wil try